# The Conditions In My First While Loop Seems To Not Be Working Properly

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

```
<script>
function Play() {
var guesses = 1
var number = 0
var points = 0
var cp = 0
var level = " "
var x = 0
while (level != "a" || "A" || "b" || "B" || "c" || "C" || "d" || "D"){
    level = prompt("Select Your Difficulty");
    if (level == "a" || "A" || "b" || "B" || "c" || "C" || "d" || "D") {
        if (level == "a" || level == "A") {
            x = 30;
        }
        else if (level == "b" || level == "B") {
            x = 50;
        }
        else if (level == "c" || level == "C") {
            x = 70;
        }
        else if (level == "d" || level == "D") {
            x = 100;
        }
    }
    else if (level != "a" || "A" || "b" || "B" || "c" || "C" || "d" || "D") {
        if (level == null) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            alert("You Went Sphagetti On Your Keyboard And Missed");
    }
    }
}
var answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * x) + 1;
number = prompt("What Is Your First Guess?");
if (number == null) {
    return;
}
//The Beginning Of The While Loop
while (guesses <= 4) {
    //Give The User A Point And Restart The Guesses
    //Generate A New Number For Them To Guess
    if (number == answer) {
        alert("You Guessed Correctly! You Get One Point!");
        alert("The Number Will Now Change, But Will Still Be Within 1-30");
        guesses = 1;
        points = points + 1;
        answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * x) + 1;
        number = prompt("What Is Your Guess For The New Number?");
        if (number == null){
            return;
        }
        //If The Number The User Guessed Equals The Answer
        //Go Back To The Start Of The Loop
        else if (number == answer) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    if (number < answer) {
        alert("Wrong! The Number Is To Low! NACHO CHEESE");
    }
    else if (number > answer) {
        alert("Wrong! The Number Is To High! YOU ARE SHELLFISH!");
    }
    number = prompt("You've Made " + guesses + " Guess(es)");
    if (number == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (number == answer) {
        continue;
    }
    else if (number != answer) {
        guesses = guesses + 1;
    }
}
//If The User Gets Wrong On All 5 Guesses
//Tell Them They Lost And Give Them The Answer
//Display Their Total Points
alert("You Have Guessed Incorrectly 5 Times. The Number Was " + answer);
cp = points.toString();
document.getElementById("points").innerHTML= "Point Streak: " + cp;
}
</script>-
```

Hello, I was wondering why the conditions in my first while loop do not seem to be working properly. When I enter in a letter that should break out of the loop since the condition is while it is not equal to one of these letters, it just ends up asking me to again to ("Select Your Difficulty"). Before it was also giving me the "You Went Spaghetti On Your Keyboard And Missed") When I entered in a letter that should break out of the loop... If I am not mistaken if should not even be entering that else if in the first place if I enter in one of those letters right? Please guide me where I went wrong.

Comment: your while loop is wrong buddy.. it should be something like `(level != "a" || 
 level != "A" || level != "b"....so on )` ... this is the same in your if check too.. Better would be to keep those alphabets in a array and then check if `level` exists in the array like `var arr = ["a","A","b","B","c","C","d","D"];` and then in the while check you can do `while(arr.indexOf("level") == -1)` same in you `if` check too.. here `-1` result says the items is not in array and if the result is 0 and above it means the item exists in array.. hope this helps

Comment: @RajshekarReddy Thank you so much!!! I did need to add level after each OR, and also I noticed that it kept looping over and over because it I should have been using AND's instead of OR's for the while loop condition. But I have since then been using arrays and noticed that it makes my life a bit easier. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. It really helped me :).

Comment: Glad to help. No problems :)